# Flex/Flash builder - app works in simulator or iOS but not android - HTTPService

Tags: android, xml, actionscript-3, apache-flex, flash-builder

Ok, I have an app I've been writing in Flash builder that makes several HTTPService requests to a server to gather some data about the user. In one view it goes and downloads a string from a server, it then splits the string using delimiter ":" and then adds the components to an array to populate a Spinnerlist. In the simulator this works great, if I package the app for iOS and install it on my iPhone - it works great. But when I try to run it to my Android device, it doesn't work. It acts as though it is working, it loads the view with the SpinnerList on it but the list is empty. I can't seem to figure it out.

Some things I've tried: the XML settings i have enabled the internet access to the android device, in fact, earlier in the app when the user logs in the phone make a very similar server call which works fine on all devices.

This issue has me completely dumbfounded, and help would be greatly appreciated!!
here is the code that makes the request and separates the data.

HttpService Request:

```
<mx:HTTPService id="CommonHTTP" url="http://dispatch.americantaxi.com:8080/AT/servlet/OnlineOrderServices?command=retrieveCustomerCommonPlaces&amp;customerId={data.ID}" resultFormat="text"/>
```

Sorting code:

```
protected function button5_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
        {

            PickUpType = "Common";
            data.PickUpType = PickUpType;

            var CommonDataString:String = new String(CommonHTTP.lastResult);
            trace("String " + CommonDataString)
            var Arr1:Array = [];
            Arr1 = CommonDataString.split("|");
            trace("arr1 length " + Arr1.length);
            var ArrCount:Number = new Number(Arr1.length);
            var Arr2:Array = [];
            for (var i:Number = 0; i < (ArrCount - 1); i++) {
                var currentSelect:String = new String(Arr1[i]);

                Arr2 = currentSelect.split(":");
                var currentName:String = new String(Arr2[1]);
                trace("Add: " + currentName);

                CommonPlacesArray.addItem(currentName);
            }

            data.CommonPlacesArray = CommonPlacesArray;
            navigator.pushView(CommonPlaces, data);

        }
```

Comment: Have you stepped through the code in debug mode?  Have you watched what is being returned in the result handler of the HTTP Service?

Comment: Agree your best bet here is to hook up the debugger while executing on the phone and step through the result handler.